# Ubuntu 18.04 Server VM - Netplan broken/gone after network adapter change on host

Tags: networking, netplan

I had some issues with my Hyper-V host so shut down all my vm's, reconfigured host (new virtual switch) then reconfigured networking before restarting the vm's. 42 of the vm's came up fine, one didn't.

Netplan was configured prior to the shutdown/restart but afterwards only an incomplete yaml file, not even the default yaml with dhcp. eth0 is down at this point. I replace the config in the yaml and "sudo netplan apply" gives me netplan command is not found.

/usr/share/netplan/../../.. exists but there isn't a single file in the directory tree.

I added an IP and brought eth0 up with `ifconfig eth0 172.16.xx.xx/xx up` and attempted reinstall netplan but no luck. Without resolvconf or netplan installed I have no dns. Attempted pinging archive.ubuntu.com and adding the ip to /etc/hosts but still I get the following:

```
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports Release
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was stupid. I realized while attempting to wget the .deb from the ubuntu repository that I had not added a default gateway...

sudo route add default gw

problem solved.

Still wondering what happened to netplan to begin with though...